# Match a uploaded image with another image using machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning

Hopefully someone may point me in the right direction for this problem of mine, what would be the best ML algorithm to use in order to match an image with another (or very similar) image on the web? When i say best i am thinking about performance and also speed on the user's end

Thanks!

Comment: Have you heard of "siamese network"? Check here for an example: https://www.kaggle.com/kmader/image-similarity-with-siamese-networks

Comment: Never heard of it, looks very interesting, thanks for the links!